# Is it ok to create a prototype just to save internal object properties?

Tags: javascript

When I instantiate an object in my javascript framework, I add a `__listeners__` property to it. But then the `console.log` output shows the`__listeners__` property first.

I don't want the `__listeners__` property showing up in the beginning of the `console.log` output, since its an internal property in my framework. I'm looking for a way to somehow push the `__listeners__` property to the end of the object.

The only solution I have so far is by adding an extra object in the prototype chain.

```
   create: function() {
       var objTemplate=Object.create(this);
       var newObj=Object.create(objTemplate);
       objTemplate.__listeners__=[];
       return newObj;
   }
```

But, the above solution, will cause slower lookups through the prototype chain and creates a slightly unintuitive object hierarchy.

Is this ok or is there a better solution to this problem?

Comment: Do you need it to run in an environment that doesn't have support for ES2015 `WeakMap`s yet? (Note that WeakMaps cannot be shimmed, so even using a transpiler and shims doesn't let you use them.)

Comment: Maybe it shows up first, because the output is ordered alphabetically. Meaning _ precedes the letter "a"?

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly: Yeah, it depends a lot on the console implementation.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have no clue what a `WeakMap` is, will check it out. But at this point, I'd like the framework to be as compatible as possible to browsers, though I really doubt older versions of IE will make it in my list

Comment: Creating a framework nowadays using bare es5 without babel or typescript is kinda weird... And the more weird thing is to care about the console output order.

Comment: @Bitonator: Indeed, `WeakMap` isn't aavailable prior to IE11 (and IE11's version isn't fully-compliant).

Comment: @smnbbrv one of the things I find very irritating is a `console.log` output that shows shows garbage that I can't use to quickly debug my code. So obviously, I don't want to have that when I design a framework lol. Maybe its just me being a picky idiot.

Comment: @Bitonator: If you can't use `WeakMap` (and if I were writing a general-purpose JavaScript library right now I wouldn't be relying on it), I'd suggest just a `__internalData` member (or similar) on the object that has all the private stuff, and call it good. :-) That's just one tree, so hopefully not burying the information you/your users are trying to find in a forest.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'll give the `WeakMap` a shot, an interesting thing is that I don't have this kind of initialisation when an object is extended, its only instances which will have that extra object in the prototype chain...so, unless some coder does something whacky like create an instance and then extend it into a larger hierarchy of objects, he'll just have to deal with a small performance hit with this approach...I think.

Answer (score 4):

If you can use ES2015's `WeakMap`, which cannot be shimmed on older environments (but see ¹), creating information related to an object that isn't stored *on* the object is one of their use cases:

```
const privateDataCache = new WeakMap();

class MyThingy {
    constructor() {
        privateDataCache.set(this, {listeners: []});
        // ...
    }
    addListener(listener) {
        privateDataCache.get(this).listeners.push(listener);
    }
    removeListener(listener) {
        const data = privateDataCache.get(this);
        data.listeners = data.listeners.filter(l => l !== listener);
    }
}
```

Because the keys in a `WeakMap` are *weakly-held*, they don't prevent your objects from being garbage collected, and the private data stored in the `WeakMap` is removed when the key becomes invalid.

That won't work in IE prior to IE11, though. (And IE11's `WeakMap` is missing some things, but nothing the above relies on.)

---

¹ Although `WeakMap` cannot be correctly shimmed/polyfilled, the *syntax* can be shimmed/polyfilled. [core.js](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js) does that, implementing the `WeakMap` by storing data on the key itself. So while not correct, it may well be what you want for your use case.

Comment: You beet me to it ;)

Comment: It's not true that WeakMaps cannot be shimmed; core-js (among others) does exactly that.

Comment: @Frxstrem: You cannot **correctly** shim `WeakMap`, because you cannot correctly implement removing entries whose keys have disappeared. You can shim the syntax, but that's not at all the same thing. core.js's shim stores values as "hidden properties" on keys, though, which may well be sufficient for the OP's purposes. I'll update to flag that up.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I just tested core-js on Node v0.10 (which doesn't have a native WeakMap implementation) and it does indeed garbage collect the values of the weak map after the keys are no longer referenced... ([this](http://hastebin.com/dedecoduju.js) was the program I wrote to test).

Comment: @Frxstrem: Yes, see above -- because they store them as hidden properties on keys. Which isn't correct (but does at least clean up).